# Why does JS code work absurdly when hosted?

Tags: javascript, hosting, web-hosting

I was trying to create a website that I can use to upload Images to. I used the code below to display all the images on the selected folder.

```
 <script>
    var folder = "uploads/Chemistry/Acid-Base-Salt/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
               
                $("div").append( "<a data-fancybox='gallery' href='"+ folder + val +"' data-caption='"+ val +"'' data-width='300' data-height='600'> <img src='"+ folder + val+"' width='300' height='600'/> </a>" );
            } 
        });
    }
});

$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
    loop:true,
    buttons: [
        "zoom",
        "share",
        "slideShow",
        "fullScreen",
        "download",
        "thumbs",
        "close"
    ],
    animationEffect: "zoom-in-out"
})
</script>
```

When I execute this code on Apache localhost it works perfectly, however, if I enter the website which is hosted (I enter by the domain), It lists and displays each image twice.

The whole code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- 1. Add latest jQuery and fancybox files -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>

    <!--<a href="image_1.jpg" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Caption #1">
        <img src="thumbnail_1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>-->

    <form action="acid-base-salt.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Yuklemek icin resim sec:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Et" name="submit">
    </form>
        <script>
            var folder = "uploads/Chemistry/Acid-Base-Salt/";
        
        $.ajax({
            url : folder,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                    
                        $(".test").append( "<a data-fancybox='gallery' href='"+ folder + val +"' data-caption='"+ val +"'' data-width='300' data-height='600'> <img src='"+ folder + val+"' width='300' height='600'/> </a>" );
                    } 
                });
            }
        });

        $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
            loop:true,
            buttons: [
                "zoom",
                "share",
                "slideShow",
                "fullScreen",
                "download",
                "thumbs",
                "close"
            ],
            animationEffect: "zoom-in-out"
        })
        </script>

    <div class="test"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `$("div").append(...)` will append the element to every `div` element on the page. Maybe you have more than one `div` element on your hosted page.

Comment: that's because your javascript parse the directory listing, then create img tag for each anchor link. different server (version, config, apache or nginx) might output different directory listing page

Comment: How can i solve this?

Comment: point your browser to ```localhost/uploads/Chemistry/Acid-Base-Salt/```, then ```yourhosting.domain/uploads/Chemistry/Acid-Base-Salt/```, compare them

Comment: @RalfiBahar instead of using tag selector (div) , try id (recommended ) or class selector

Comment: you might want to add a file called index.php inside "uploads/Chemistry/Acid-Base-Salt/", content of index.php ```<?php
$all = glob("./*");
foreach($all as $item) {
    echo "<a href='$item'>$item</a>";
}```

Comment: @Kristian this is not a php error. its a javascript selector issue

Comment: They are the same, but they just show the directory but nothing inside it. I still don't get why it would render the function twice for each image.

Comment: your code will print the images n times when u have n number of divisions

Comment: Even when I use class selector it prints twice @Sandrin Joy

Comment: maybe you have 2 divisions with same class

Comment: I edited in the whole code above. Can you check please?